# How to use cursor in Java to run a MySQL statement and put the results into an array?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table called 'USER', which has a 'USERNAME' field and a 'PASSWORD' field. It is part of a database, stored in a .db file.

I want to run a MySQL query on the table and get all the values in the 'USERNAME' column, then iterate over the result and put all the values into an primitive array of String values.

I would like to use the cursor Java function to execute the statement. Could you please tell me how to write and execute a MySQL statement, and how to use the result? Is it stored in a variable? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cursor Java function"? How far have you got so far? Is there any reason you don't just want to use `ResultSet`?

Comment: The implicit cursor in java is the ResultSet object, provided by JDBC. You can just write a query using JDBC and iterate on it using ResultSet method next()

Comment: Okay, sounds good, can you tell me how to do that?